# Can't fill html table from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Please help me fill table from json response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "James",
    "nickNames": [
      {}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Linda",
    "nickNames": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "lin"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "l1n"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lin"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to fill table like this:

```
<table id="users" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Nicknames</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>none</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Linda</td>
    <td>lin, l1n, Lin</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I'm already done:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myAppControllers', [])
  .controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function ($scope, User) {
    User.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.users = data;
      }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Failed: ' + reason)
      }
    )
  }]);
```

Here's my template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Users</h1>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Nicknames</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'id' track by user.id">
      <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="nickname in user.nickNames | emptyUser">{{ nickname.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem with nested array I can't split entries into one `<td>` tag.

p.s. I can't change server's api.

I saw similar issues on StackOverflow, but they are different from my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont repeat on the `td` tag - use a `span` within the `td`:

```
<td><span ng-repeat="nickname in user.nickNames | emptyUser">{{ nickname.name }} </span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see here :http://jsbin.com/vined/1/edit

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Nicknames</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in data | orderBy:'id' track by user.id">
      <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
      <td><p ng-repeat="nickname in user.nickNames | emptyUser ">{{ nickname.name }}</p></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks but data in one row looks better.

Comment: of course that depends of you if you want one row or not just use other tag then td